# How to cleanly migrate BooleanField to CharField

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have the following model:

```py
class Teacher(models.Model)
    tenured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to migrate this `BooleanField` to a `CharField` with additional options `['No', 'Pending', 'Yes']`. Like so:

```py
class Teacher(models.Model)
    TENURE_CHOICES =  [(choice,choice) for choice in ['No', 'Pending', 'Yes']]
    tenured = models.CharField(max_length=7, default='No', choices=TENURE_CHOICES)
```

Now, as I have 1000+ records already present for this model I would like to migrate them from their Boolean value to the `'Yes'/'No'` value when migrating.

How would I do this without having to store a backup of this table and reapply after migrations have taken place? Can I do this as part of the migration process?

Answer (score 4):

We run a zero downtime application on django so we can never remove a field in the same deployment as the change the model to reflect the deletion.

To migrate we rename the old field and add the new field
You could use this approach to first rename and add the new field with custom migration according to docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/writing-migrations/.

So you keep the data until you are sure everything is fine.

Once you are satisfied remove the renamed field from model -> deploy -> make migrations-> deploy again.

This variant is zero downtime complient and has the benefit of not requiring a backup or a copy of the table.

Answer (score 3):

You can create migration using makemigrations command and boolean values will be casted to chars, '1' for True and '0' for False. After that you can write simple command to swap all '0' to 'No' and all '1' to 'Yes' or even from DB level.

```
from authorization.models import TestModel
TestModel.objects.create(example_bool=True)
<TestModel: TestModel object (1)>
TestModel.objects.create(example_bool=True)
<TestModel: TestModel object (2)>
TestModel.objects.create(example_bool=True)
<TestModel: TestModel object (3)>
TestModel.objects.create(example_bool=False)
<TestModel: TestModel object (4)>
TestModel.objects.create(example_bool=False)
<TestModel: TestModel object (5)>
for x in TestModel.objects.all():
    print(x.example_bool)

1
1
1
0
0
```

Answer (score 2):

Following up on @PTomasz's solution of a simpler (but not zero-downtime) solution, here's the migration file can be patched to run it:

```
# add this:
def set_tenure_choices(apps, _schema_editor):
    Teacher = apps.get_model('main', 'Teacher')
    for tc in Teacher.objects.all():
        if tc.tenured == '1':
            tc.tenured = 'Yes'
        elif tc.tenured == '0':
            tc.tenured = 'No'
        tc.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='teacher',
            name='tenured',
            field=models.CharField(default='No', max_length=7),
        ),
        # Add this line:
        migrations.RunPython(set_tenure_choices),
    ]
```

(Note that in Django w/ mysql all CharFields even with choices are stored as a VarChar, so setting max_length=255 instead of 7 will not increase the storage space needed, but might save a migration in the future if other choices are added)

Comment: I had something like that in mind, but I don't know if it's optimal to iterate over all Teacher objects instead of doing Teacher.objects.filter(tenured='1').update(tenured='Yes') and same for 'No'. This way we do not have to get every single object instance an we do update on db level without calling Django signals

Comment: Definitely a good improvement!